# Not able to create version after adding 2GP Feature Parameters

Tags: 2gp, feature-management, sf

I have a 2GP managed package where I added a feature parameter metadata file (Integer).  I have created multiple versions of this project until adding the feature parameter metadata files.  After doing so my package create command is timing out on PollingClientTimeout.  I have increased the wait time from 10 to 15 min but no luck.  I have gone over the Salesforce docs repeatedly but am unable to find an issue.  The feature parameter file is in force/main/default/featureParameters folder.  Here is the name and contents of the file.

FeatureParameterName.featureParameterInteger-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FeatureParameterInteger xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <dataflowDirection>LmoToSubscriber</dataflowDirection>
  <masterLabel>Feature Parameter Name</masterLabel>
  <value>0</value>
</FeatureParameterInteger>
```

Comment: I deployed to a Dev Org with the `sf project deploy start` command and was able to deploy and read the values in the Developer Console with anonymous Apex but still not able to create a new version with the metadata files in the featureParameters folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Apparently, adding two feature parameter metadata files increased the time that it takes to create a version by a lot.  I set the --wait flag to 30 and it created the version.  Once that happened I found that the build # in the major.minor.patch-build had been incrementing, it just did not have time to finish and create a usable version to put into the sfdx-project.json.  Hopefully this solution helps someone try that remedy faster than I did.